# How to tackle limit question using epsilon-delta?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Consider the function, with domain $\mathbb{R}$, defined by

$$f(x)
= \begin{cases} 
      x & \text{if $x$ is rational,} \\
      -x & \text{if $x$ is irrational.} 
   \end{cases}
$$

Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0.$

---

Obviously, intuitively, the limit is $0$. But how do I prove this by definition?

---

My attempt:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $\exists\delta > 0$, such that, if $0<|x-0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$, i.e.,$|x-0|<\epsilon \Rightarrow |x|<\epsilon$.

Then, $$|f(x)-0|<\epsilon \text{ iff } |(x)-0|<\epsilon$$
$$|x|<\epsilon$$
Choose $\delta = \epsilon$ it follows that $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$.

---

Just want to see if this fulfills the proof. All critiques welcome.

---

Comment: You have already spotted the proof. Just remember to take an arbitrary epsilon, and show that your proposed delta indeed works. In this case take $\delta = \epsilon$

Comment: Hint: $|f(x)-0|=|\pm x|=|x|$.

Comment: Can you elaborate @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: Can you prove that $g(x)\to0$ as $x\to0$, where $g(x)=x$? From my previous comment, your problem is rather similar in nature.

Comment: Well haven't I technically proven that in my attempt?

Comment: Hm, it's not clear what your attempt is doing. You say that $|0-0|<\epsilon$, but I'm not sure how this relates to the previous stuff. In particular, $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I was trying to work through [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/preclimsoldirectory/PrecLimSol.html)

Comment: @sgerbhctim I'm definitely not inclined to scroll through your homework problems. Could you respond more directly as to where $|0-0|<\epsilon$ came up?

Comment: Actually you are right. I am wrong there.

Comment: Can you check edits and see if this makes more sense @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: Your proof is fine. Personally, I would've found $\delta=\epsilon$ to be a more natural choice.

Comment: Thank you very much @SimplyBeautifulArt for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the existence of a limit in our case:

> We are given $\epsilon > 0$, and we have to find a $\delta > 0$ such that *whenever $|x -0| < \delta$ is true, it must also be true that $|f(x) - 0| < \epsilon$*.

I see some problems. For one, how do you go from $|f(x) - 0| < \epsilon$ to $|0-0| < \epsilon$? Note that this is true only if $x = 0$, whereas you need to show that it is true for $|x -0| < \delta$ for some $\delta$.

Note that if for *any* $\epsilon > 0$ we pick $\delta = 0.5$, then this won't work out. An example is when $\epsilon  = 0.1$ and $x = 0.2$, then while it is true  that $|x - 0| < 0.5$, it is *not true* that $|f(x) - 0| < 0.1$. Therefore, $\delta = 0.5$ does not work for $\epsilon = 0.1$.

In our case, you believe that you intuitively have got the idea of why the limit is zero. The correct proof is as follows:

> Note that $f(x) = x$ or $-x$ depending on some circumstances. Either way, $|f(x)| = |x|$. Therefore, for *any* $x$ and $\epsilon$, $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ if and only if $|x| < \epsilon$.  Now, if we choose $\delta = \epsilon$, we see that *whenever $|x| < \delta = \epsilon$, by the above statement we have $|f(x)| < \epsilon$*. Therefore, the limit is established to be zero.

Please read this proof carefully before attempting comments. I would prefer it if you tell me exactly what the problem is.

EDIT : Okay, thank you for the response, now I will show you what exactly the squeeze theorem means.

So let's say we have three functions, $f(x),g(x),h(x)$. Now, suppose there is some point $a$, such that for $x$ "near" $a$ (that is, for $|x - a| < \delta$ for some appropriately chosen $\delta$), $f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x)$ is true. This is like putting the graph of $g$, in between both $f$ and $h$.

Now, suppose that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} h(x)$ both exist and are *equal*. What does this mean? This means that as $x$ gets closer to $a$, both  $f$ and $h$ get closer to *the same point*. But what does this imply about $g$? $g$, suffocated between $f$ and $h$, *must go to the same point*, right?

That is, a function *squeezed* between two other functions going to the same point, also must go to that point. This is the essence of the squeeze theorem, whose result would be that $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exists, and equals the limit for $f$ or $h$.

Here, if we take $g(x) = x$ if $x$ is irrational and $-x$ otherwise, then take $f(x) = -x$ and $h(x) = x$, we see that $g$ squeeze between $f$ and $h$, but both $f$ and $h$ have the limit $0$ at $x = 0$, so $g$ must also have the same limit (no $\epsilon-\delta$ business involved here).

The idea with these tricks, is to eliminate your use of $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments for these situations, and come up with more slick proofs. I hope this will motivate you to read further.

Comment: Have seen the edited proof. It is correct. I will edit this post, if you like, to explain how the squeeze logic works.

Comment: If you can include the squeeze theorem, that would be great. But my edit seems correct, right? I like the way you include the $|x|$.

Comment: Yes, your edit is correct. I will edit my answer then.

Comment: Edited. Please have a look.

Comment: This is incredible. Thank you so much. I have an additional question that I will include in the next edit

Comment: Have seen the edit. Will edit my proof.

Comment: I just added to another page.. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489991/trying-to-show-that-limit-does-not-exist)

Comment: Excellent. I will answer the question there. Also, +1 to this question.

Comment: Absolutely, you got it. You are awesome - thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof? This can be done via the squeeze theorem. In particular, try squeezing your function betweeen $-|x|$ and $|x|$.

By the way, your attempted proof is incorrect, insofar as you're assuming something "then $\exists \delta > 0$ such that..." which really, you're meant to be trying to prove. You can use my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456795/introductory-proofs-writing-class-prove-forall-x-in-mathbb-z-exists-y-in/2456807#2456807) to guide you in the writing of these proofs. Though ignored, it's quality is very high.

Comment: Can you help me work through this?

Comment: Having a hard time relating the suggested guide to this proof.

Comment: @sgerbhctim Could you be more specific as to what's giving you a hard time?

Comment: @sgerbhctim, did you Google "squeeze theorem?" If you don't search for unfamiliar terms in people's answer before asking them for further help, you're going to end up annoying people...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the absolute value of your function is just the function $g(x)=|x|$.

The purpose of this hint is that in taking the absolute value of your function (as you do in a delta epsilon proof) and seeking to bound it by a given epsilon, the difference in the functions definition on the rationals and irrationals is lost.

i.e. take $\epsilon>0$ fixed. Then 
$$
|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|=|x|<\delta
$$
so it will suffice to take $\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: Not true, probably not useful to the OP..

Comment: OK, what's $f(\sqrt2)$? - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/893460)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel $f(\sqrt{2})=-\sqrt{2}$, $|f(x)|=\sqrt{2}$, which is my point

Comment: @ParclyTaxel please let me know if this addressed your concerns, if not I will go ahead and delete it myself.

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$