# Trying to show that limit does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Consider the function, with domain $\mathbb{R}$, defined by

$$f(x)
= \begin{cases} 
      x & \text{if $x$ is rational,} \\
      -x & \text{if $x$ is irrational.} 
   \end{cases}
$$

When referring to [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489939/how-to-tackle-limit-question-using-epsilon-delta/2489973?noredirect=1#comment5143781_2489973).

**Q)** Prove that for any $a \neq 0$, $f$ does not have a limit at $a$.

Is it sufficient for me to say:

Leading towards a contradiction, for $a=0$, $f$ does not have a limit at a. By the above, we see that this is not true, because when $a=0$, there exists a limit which has been proven. Hence, for any $a\neq0$, $f$ does not have a limit at $a$.

Comment: No, that is not sufficient.  It does not even make sense.

Comment: Why exactly? Isn't the contradiction $\neg P \rightarrow Q$

Comment: Would contraposition make sense?

Comment: For one thing you state "there exists a limit which has been proven", but neglected to do so.  For another you then jump from that to claiming the function cannot have a limit elsewhere, but neglected to justify why for.

Comment: Your reasoning seems to be that for any function $f(x)$, if $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ is defined, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ is undefined for any $a\neq0$. This is clearly absurd. A good self-test is to ask whether you have used the definitions provided. Your argument doesn't reference $f(x)$ anywhere at all, so this is a red flag.

Comment: Start with a definition of what limit means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem here, is that the contradiction of the statement "for any $a \neq 0$, $f$ does not have a limit  at $a$" , is *not* "for $a = 0$, $f$ does not have a limit at $a$". The answer is : "there is some $a \neq 0$ for which the limit exists", Therefore, behaviour of $f$ at $0$, is not required to answer this question.

In words : The limit of $f(x)$ at $x = a$ exists, if bringing $x$ close enough to $a$ means that $f(x)$ can be brought close enough to "some number", which we call the limit at that point.

Coming to the answer itself, we have to show that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ does *not* exist. Why could this be true? Well, let $a$ be a rational point. There are plenty of rational and irrational points near $a$. Roughly, if $x$ a rational point close to $a$, then we know that $f(x) = x$ is very close to $f(a) = a$. But, if $x$ is an irrational point close to $a$ then is $f(x) = -x$ close to $f(a) = a$? We are trying to say that if $x$ is close enough to $a$, then $f(x)$ should be close enough to $f(a)$. But here, we are landing up, with both $x$ and $-x$ being close to $a$. How can this happen?

Well, it can happen if $x$ and $-x$ are close to each other i.e. $x$ is close to $0$, and therefore at $a =0$ we see that the limit exists intuitively. at other points, $x$ and $-x$ simply wouldn't be close to each other: if one of them is close to $a$, the other is going to be far away, and that's the problem.

A rigorous proof: See, in the limit definition, for each $\epsilon$ we find a $\delta$, right? Here, I will show you an $\epsilon$ for which no $\delta$ will work! And therefore, the limit wouldn't exist!

> Let $a \neq 0$. Put $\epsilon = \frac{|a|}{2}$. Note that $\epsilon > 0$ (this is important, right!) Finally, let $\delta > 0$ be any positive real number which is such that $|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$. This means, by the triangle inequality, that $f(a) + \frac {|a|}{2} > f(x) > f(a) - \frac{|a|}{2}$. Since we know that $|f(a)| = |a|$, the above shows that $f(x)$ has the same sign for all $|x - a| < \delta$ i.e. it is either positive for all such $x$, or negative for all such $x$. However, if I pick $x$ such that $|x - a| < \delta$, that is opposite to $a$ i.e if $a$ is irrational, then $x$ is irrational , and vice-versa, then $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ would definitely have opposite sign, which contradicts our earlier statement. Hence, we see  that no $\delta$ exists for this $\epsilon > 0$, which finishes the arugment that the limit does not exist.

Vitally, the fact that $a \neq 0$ was used in the first line itself in this argument.

Again, the usual comment : read the proof carefully, and you can get back for further queries.

Comment: I'm taking my time soaking up this information sentence by sentence.

Comment: Excellent. It can only benefit you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't quite understood how contradiction (more specifically negation) works.

The thing you want to prove is of the form

> Given any *[type of thing]* $a$, it is not true that *some property of $a$ holds*.

The negation ('opposite' if you like) of this statement would be

> There is **some** *[type of thing]* $a$, such that it **is true** that *some property of $a$ holds*.

For example, the negation of

> Every person in this forum is unhelpful.

would be

> There is one person in this forum who is helpful.

---

Here, if you want to proceed by contradiction, you want to claim that the negation is true, i.e.

> Suppose that there is some $a \neq 0$ such that $f(x) \to f(a)$ as $x\to a$.

---

- **Edit** part 1: I think you ask if contradiction of $P \to Q$ is $(\neg P) \to Q$. The answer is: no! It is $\neg (P \to Q)$. Since $P \to Q \equiv (\neg P) \vee Q$, it follows that $$\neg (P \to Q) = P \wedge \neg Q$$ so that contradiction suggests you can satisfy $(a\neq0)\wedge(f \text{ cts at } a)$ as suggested above.
- **Edit** part 2: You mention *contraposition* in a comment. This would be sensible: $P \to Q \equiv \neg Q \to \neg P$, so it suffices to prove $f \text{ cts at } a \implies a = 0$ instead.

You could definitely make this work as well.

Comment: This makes so much sense. Would contraposition make sense as well? Does it make sense for me to prove - $f$ has a limit, if $a=0$.

Comment: @sgerbhctim I've replied to your comments about the underlying logic. (I've avoided talking about the analysis side of things for now.)

Answer (score 0):

> Prove that if $a\neq 0$, then $f( )$ does not have a limit at $a$.

Start with your definition of limit. Examine it to see if you understand why $f(x)$ will not approach a limit as $x$ approaches $a$, *except* when $a=0$.

Hint: What do you know about rational and irrational numbers and their placement on the number line?

Answer (score -3):

If $a$ rational, $f(a)=a$ and $f(a+{e\over n})=-a-{e\over n})$. We have $lim_na+{e\over n}=a$ and $lim_nf(a+{e\over n})=lim_n-a-{e\over n}=-a\neq f(a)$.

If $a$ is irrational, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $a_n, lima_n=a, a_n\in\mathbb{Q}$. We deduce that $lim_nf(a_n)=lim_na_n=a$ and $f(a)=-a$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Comment: why ? what is the question ?